# How prevent React Native FlatList height from changing when the content changes?

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

I have a main View with a top view and a bottom view, in the following flex configuation:

```
container view: flex 1 (fills the whole height)
   -header view: flex 1 (fills 25% of the container)
   -bottom view: flex 3 (fills 75% of the container)
```

The bottom view contains a `FlatList`.

The problem is that the layout changes when the amount of items in the FlatList changes. The flatlist starts with 3 items, then it looks ok. When the amount of items changes to 20, the height becomes too high and the flatlist height + header height become higher than the screen height.

I want the flatlist to keep the same height regardless of how many items are in the list.

React native view:

```
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.topblock}>
        <Text>a list</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.bottomblock}>
          <FlatList
            style={styles.liststyle}
            data={mycooldata}
            renderItem={createListItem}
            keyExtractor={item => item.name}
          />
      </View>
    </View>
```

the list item

```
const createListItem = ({ item }) => (
  <View style={styles.item} >
        <Text style={styles.title} >{item.title}</Text>
  </View>
)
```

And the CSS

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'lightgrey',
    marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight || 0,
  },
  topblock:{
    flex:1,
    backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
  },
  bottomblock:{
    flex:3
  },
  liststyle:{
    backgroundColor:'lightgreen',
    height:'100%' // also tried flex 1 or leaving it out entirely
  },
  item: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(150,150,250)',
    padding: 8,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 14,
  },
});
```

Comment: I've tried your code with different data and it's working fine, the problem causes maybe in createListItem, can you share code of createListItem.

Comment: I added the function. You can also see the whole thing here: https://snack.expo.dev/@eerk/pokemon-loader

Comment: By the way, it DOES work on iOS. Only the Web preview acts weird. I haven't tried Android.

Comment: Yes, I've checked  on android and on ios and it's working fine, for web there is issue, you should give fixed height.

Comment: Thanks for checking.It's still strange that the height of the flatlist can change. But as long as this only happens in the Expo web preview, it should be no problem.

Answer (score 1):

you should wrap the `FlatList` in a `View'. that` View` will have your desired  fixed height then you are all done

or you can use `contentContainerStyle` of `FlatList`.

Comment: Thanks! This works for me in iOS but the web player changes the size of the flatlist when more items are loaded. Maybe it's just a peculiarity of the web player?